# Facebook debugger not finding correct og:image or refusing to use it

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-opengraph, meta

I run a Wordpress blog. Here's the URL to our main page: http://theoriginalsocitey.com

For some reason, when links to posts on our site are shared, the featured image is not correctly detected. When I put a link to a post through the Facebook debugger, some of the usual minor errors come up that do for all sites, including those that work perfectly. I've tried fixing the "tags in body" error with success, but it didn't fix the problem, so it is not the issue.

All other OG tags are displaying correctly, just the og:image has the issue. The debugger even acts like it knows what image to use, but refuses to do so. It will say the correct image but say "the image is not large enough" when it clearly is, for all posts.

Can someone please help me figure this out? It's been days of countless different attempts of fixing this including plugin deactivation, reactivation and new installations and nothing has worked.

Here's an example of a post URL to use for debugging: http://theoriginalsociety.com/quest-castro-jon-bellion-logic-24-freestyle/

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the open graph image is too small (150x150), therefor Facebook is using the larger image it found on the page. It's in your best interest to give Facebook as large an image as possible.

[https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content/][1]

> og:image – This is an image associated with your media. We suggest
>   that you use an image of at least 1200x630 pixels.

Try providing a much larger image and see if that solves the problem.